# Using Parse to get number of Cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve the number of Cells in a UITableView using Parse.

The return is being called quicker than the background task is finishing, and thus the number of cells is equal to zero.

Here is the code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    __block int rows;


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"bills"];
    [query whereKey:@"houseId" equalTo:@1];
    [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            rows = count;
            NSLog(@"in block = %d",rows);
        } else {
            rows = 0;
        }
    }];

    NSLog(@"out of block = %d",rows);
    return rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous method that returns instantly and runs the block only once its done with the network call so the `numberOfRowsInSection` doesn't wait for that async call to finish

One way to get the count would be to have a `@property NSArray *stuff` and load the objects from parse in a different method, `loadStuffFromParse` for example and in the completion block of that call do something like

I'd probably have the method in `viewWillAppear` (and hook into it in your refresh controls action if you have pull to refresh enabled) in something like

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self loadStuffFromParse];
}
```

And just have something like

```
#pragma mark - Implementation
- (void)loadStuffFromParse {
    // Do anything we need to do before loading like updating user interface        

    // [PFQuery loadStuffFromParse:^(NSArray *data, NSError *err ){
    //    if (!err) {
    //      self.stuff = data; // defined in @interface
    //      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //        [self.tableView reloadData];
    //      });
    //    } else {
    //      handle the error
    //    }
    //}];

}
```

Or something like that, however you decide to.

And in the `numberOfRowsInSection` assuming you only have one section you could do

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {
    return [self.stuff count];
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the query?